# ValueError while predicting from tf saved_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, valueerror

I have saved a DNNestimator, and now I am trying to use that model to predict on some data.

Model training:

```
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x", dimension=500)]

classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
feature_columns=feature_columns,
hidden_units=[500],
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4),
n_classes=18,
dropout=0,
model_dir=None)

train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
x={'x': train_vec.values},
y=train.code.astype(np.int32),
num_epochs=None,
batch_size=50,
shuffle=True)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=1000)

feature_spec = {'x':tf.FixedLenFeature(shape= [500],dtype=np.float32)}
serving_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn( feature_spec)
export_path = "path/to/export"
classifier.export_savedmodel(export_path,serving_fn)
```

I am trying to predict here:

```
a=np.expand_dims(test_vec.iloc[0].values,axis=0)
predict_fn = tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(export_path_folder)
predictions = predict_fn({"inputs":a})
```

Train_vec and test_vec are dataframes with 500 columns (features). I get the following error while predicting:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 500) for Tensor u'input_example_tensor:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

Following is my saved_model_cli:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_STRING
  shape: (-1)
  name: input_example_tensor:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_STRING
  shape: (-1, 18)
  name: dnn/head/Tile:0
 outputs['scores'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_FLOAT
  shape: (-1, 18)
  name: dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/classify
```

Very new to tensorflow, any help or direction would be valuable.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Work around:

Could not solve the above error, but a DNNClassifier "warm start" worked.

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
feature_columns=feature_columns,
hidden_units=[500],
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4),
n_classes=18,
dropout=0,
warm_start_from=export_path_folder)
```

And then use classifier.predict